# How to solve Private bytes (Native memory) leak?

Tags: c#, debugging, memory-leaks, pinvoke

I'm developing a C# application which seems to have a leak.
I've used memory profiler and found that my

**private bytes** keep increasing but **Bytes in all Heaps** do not, which means that probably it's a native memory leak

Now I'm stuck, how do I find memory leaks in native code ?

Comment: Do you know where's the leak? We can't help you without the code...

Comment: You don't write native code in C#. Surely the only thing you can do is ensure that you're handling the InterOp properly?

Comment: This is a common problem with profilers, they tell you more than you wanted to know.  Growing private bytes isn't unusual, it can take a while before it stabilizes.  Do you actually get OutOfMemory exceptions?  If not then do flip the ignore bit for this.

Comment: @Karel Frajtak - and if i tell you that the code is GOOGLE's next engine, would you let me keep it private ?

Comment: Stumbled upon this from GOOGLE, wondering if I'm using GOOGLE's next engine with the memory leak Erez was working on.

Answer (score 5):

First, if you have a dump of the leaking process, you can open it in WinDbg and issue the command :
!address -summary

- if RegionUsageHeap is large, then it should be a native memory leak
- if RegionUsageIsVAD, then it should be a .NET memory leak.

If this is a native leak, then you have 2 options :

- Use DebugDiag : when prompt, choose 'Native Memory leak and Handle leak', choose the process you want to diagnose, and start working with the application until you experiment the memory leak. When complete, generate a full dump of the application (right click on the leak rule and select Full user dump). You can then analyze the generated dump (you'll need to have the symbols properly configured for this to work efficiently) : on 'advanced analysis' tab, select 'Memory pressure analyzers', open the dump file and press 'Start analysis'. This produces and html report you can analyze. You can refer to this [page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/01/14/debugging-native-memory-leaks-with-debug-diag-1-1.aspx) for a detailed walkthrough.
- Use Application Verifier / WinDbg. In application verifier, select your application (.exe). In tests page, be sure Basics/Heaps is selected. In the lower pane, be sure 'Traces' is set to true. Once the configuration saved, re-run the application and generate a full dump when the leak occurs. Don't forget to clean application flags after the dump is generated. Then you can open the dump from within WinDbg, and investigate the leak with the help of '!heap' command. In particular, '!heap -l' will give you a list of leaked blocks, '!heap -p -a ' will show the details of a block, including the call stack of allocation.

If this is a .NET leak, there are third party tools to troubleshoot it. Starting from version 1.2, DebugDiag is also enable to perform .NET memory leak analysis (never tried this however).

Answer (score 3):

Diagnosing native memory leaks in a managed application is (at least initially) very similar to diagnosing memory leaks in any other native application.

The way I normally approach these problems is to get the process to leak a large amount of memory, take a full process dump and then examine the dump to see what is using the most memory.  For example if your process has a normal / initial private bytes of ~20MB but you can get your process to leak memory until it has ~200MB of private bytes, then there is a good chance that ~180MB of that memory is leaked - generally speaking whatever has the most memory allocated is where you should start looking.

Microsoft have a very useful tool called [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24370) - initially developed for use in diagnosing memory leaks in IIS it is a very vesatile tool and very handy when dealing with memory issues.  If you give it a crash dump it will perform some analysis and should (at the very least) tell you what module has allocated all of that memory, you can then start looking more specifically at how that module is used.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give you a solid response without more information, but it sounds like the lib you are trying to use has a memory leak. You'll need to the lib with the appropriate tools, depending on the language it was written in. If you don't have the lib's source, contact the developers and have them fix the leak.

If you can post the name of the library and some of your source code (as well as the native method signatures), we might be able to give you some more specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

private bytes in heaps managed by .net framework,  you need use professional tool to analysis your source. such like use red gate memory profiler, find object created but not being disposed.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I had the best results when hunting memory leaks using the [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/).

([Or other tools](http://www.google.com/search?q=.net%20memory%20profiler), personally I had best experiences with ANTS)