# High unused memory in .NET application - possible memory leak

Tags: .net, performance, memory-leaks, high-availability

Private bytes are still growing, after 20 mins it grows up to ~3GB used memory and it's still growing.

Application details:

- it's small web api, but it receives many requests (a few hundred per minute)
- .net framework 4.5.2
- api uses ado.net for communicating with database, all connections and commands are disposed after communication end

On attached results you'll see that there are a lot of unused memory allocated to .NET. It might be unmanaged memory leak? Heap size is constantly. See the results:

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7900433/1207195

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by IIS... after switching web api to OWIN self host problem was gone, now memory usage is around **20mb**